# Flat CSV file to nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object, nested

I have a CSV file as follows:

| PersonID | Name | Game | Date | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | John | Tennis | 01/01/2023 | 150 |
| 131 | Amanda | Hockey | 01/02/2023 | 134 |
| 123 | John | Tennis | 01/02/2023 | 140 |
| 134 | Peter | Tennis | 02/02/2023 | 127 |

What steps do i need to de to get this:

```
Tennis:

  John:

     Total_score: 290
     Played_games:
         01/01/2023   150
         01/02/2023   140
  Peter:

     Total_score: 127
     Played games:
         02/02/2023   127
Hockey:

  Amanda:

     Total_score: 134
     Played_games:
         01/02/2023   134
```

The purpose of this is to make a scoreboard grouped at Game>Person.
We want to summarize the scores of the played games.

I already tried different things. I got the games list without duplicates and so on. But what is the best practice to make a object?

I read about mapping, filtering and so on, but can't find a fitting solution for me. Maybe I think to complex.

At the moment i have the following Javascript array:

```js
const scores = [
      {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":151},
      {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "25/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":178},
      {"PersonID": "55513","Date": "01/12/2024", "game": "Hockey", "name":"Piet", "score":166},
      {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "10/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":188},
      {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "06/12/2024", "game": "Football", "name":"John", "score":133},
      {"PersonID": "33245","Date": "24/12/2024", "game": "Baseball", "name":"Marie", "score":121},
      {"PersonID": "63542","Date": "11/12/2024", "game": "Kitesurfing", "name":"Peter", "score":185},
    ]
```

This is how i filtered the games type

```js
    var arrGames = [];
    scores.filter(function(item){
      var i = arrGames.findIndex(x => x.game== item.game);
      if(i <= -1){
        arrGames.push({game: item.game});
      }
      return null;
    });
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arrGames, null, 2));
```

The next step is that i need to add the persons as child to the game. How can i arrange this? I know it can be done with some advanced loops. But for my learning process step by step would be the best :)

Comment: `I already tried different things. I got the games list without duplicates and so on` can you please show us this code, as it will give us more detail on the context you're working under, ie. how you're reading the CSV data, what libraries are in use, and if you're doing this client or server side.

Comment: Hi Rory, i use plain javascript. Importing the csv is working for me. Maybee the question should be how to "unflatten" the javascript array to a multidimensional object. The code runs client side.

Comment: That would be a better question to ask, if you already have managed to get the CSV content in to a format that JS can work with. Please do include your current attempt though, so we can help you to debug it

Comment: Hi Rory, i added the array i have at the moment.

Comment: I added the loop for getting the games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

```js
const scores = [
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":151},
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "25/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":178},
  {"PersonID": "55513","Date": "01/12/2024", "game": "Hockey", "name":"Piet", "score":166},
  {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "10/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":188},
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "06/12/2024", "game": "Football", "name":"John", "score":133},
  {"PersonID": "33245","Date": "24/12/2024", "game": "Baseball", "name":"Marie", "score":121},
  {"PersonID": "63542","Date": "11/12/2024", "game": "Kitesurfing", "name":"Peter", "score":185},
];

var end = {};

scores.forEach(function(a) {
    let game = a.game;
    let player = a.name;
    let dt = a.Date;
    let score = a.score;

    if(!end.hasOwnProperty(game)) {
        end[game] = {};
    }

    if(!end[game].hasOwnProperty(player)) {
        end[game][player] = {
            "Total_score" : 0,
            "Played_games" : []
        };
    }

    end[game][player]["Total_score"] += score;
    end[game][player]["Played_games"].push({[dt]:score});
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(end));
```

---

**Explanations**

By looping through your `scores` array, we're picking up what you need for the end result.

The first test, `if(!end.hasOwnProperty(game)) {...}` is simply assigning the current game as the key in the `end` object, if it's not already there. For example, in our first run, `end` is empty, and the first game we're picking up from your `scores` array is `tennis`.

Next, we're checking if within the specific game (tennis in our first run) there's a player we're currently getting. If the player is not within our specific game, we're putting them there, and giving them a zero score and an empty array of dates.

Finally, we're filling up our keys with an incremented score and date/score values we've picked in our current `forEach` run.

This gives us:

```
{
    "tennis": {
        "John": {
            "Total_score": 329,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "31/12/2024": 151
                },
                {
                    "25/12/2024": 178
                }
            ]
        },
        "Klaas": {
            "Total_score": 188,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "10/11/2024": 188
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Hockey": {
        "Piet": {
            "Total_score": 166,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "01/12/2024": 166
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Football": {
        "John": {
            "Total_score": 133,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "06/12/2024": 133
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Baseball": {
        "Marie": {
            "Total_score": 121,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "24/12/2024": 121
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Kitesurfing": {
        "Peter": {
            "Total_score": 185,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "11/12/2024": 185
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, Amanda's not mentioned anywhere in your example JSON array, even though she's in the table in the beginning of your question - that's why she's not present in the `end` result.

Please note that this solution is not covering the case when a player has played more than one game on a specific date. If you need that as well, let me know in the comments.

---

**EDIT**

If you want to cover the cases when a player has played more than once in a single day, the original code will already do that for you. However, if you want to sum the entire day up, you would need to change the current code to the following:

```js
// Original array reduced to only tennis players, for simplicity's sake
const scores = [
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":151},
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "25/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":178},
  {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "10/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":188},
  // The one below was added to illustrate what we're doing
  {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":22},
];

let end = {};

scores.forEach(function(a) {
    let game = a.game;
    let player = a.name;
    let dt = a.Date;
    let score = a.score;

    if(!end.hasOwnProperty(game)) {
        end[game] = {};
    }

    if(!end[game].hasOwnProperty(player)) {
        end[game][player] = {
            "Total_score" : 0,
            "Played_games" : []
        };
    }

    end[game][player]["Total_score"] += score;

    // Let'sheck if there's already an entry for the specific player,
    // and the specific date, which is actually a key in our array
    let existingDate = end[game][player]["Played_games"].find(tmp => Object.keys(tmp)[0] === dt);

    if(existingDate) {
        // We've already had the current date, that's why
        // we're incrementing the score
        existingDate[dt] += score;
    } else {
        // existingDate is undefined - the current date for the 
        // current player does not exist, so we add it
        end[game][player]["Played_games"].push({[dt]:score});
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(end));
```

This gives us:

```
{
    "tennis": {
        "John": {
            "Total_score": 351,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "31/12/2024": 173
                },
                {
                    "25/12/2024": 178
                }
            ]
        },
        "Klaas": {
            "Total_score": 188,
            "Played_games": [
                {
                    "10/11/2024": 188
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT #2**

If we need to take into consideration the new conditions:

1. Only the best three scores across multiple dates for a single gametype and a single person (e.g. the best three scores for John in tennis, for all the games they played) are used for counting the total score
2. The results need to be sorted by score (total score for players for a single gametype, and within the best three for a specific player)

our code becomes this (expand the snippet to see the full code):

```js
const scores = [
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":151},
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "25/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":178},
    {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "10/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":188},
    // The ones below were added to simplify what we're doing - the other sports
    // were removed for brevity
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "31/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":22},
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "11/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":42},
    {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "01/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":18},
    {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "11/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":88},
    {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "12/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":38},
    {"PersonID": "24244","Date": "13/11/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"Klaas", "score":45},
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "21/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":220},
    {"PersonID": "1234","Date": "01/12/2024", "game": "tennis", "name":"John", "score":197},
];

  
let end = {};

scores.forEach(function(a) {
    let game = a.game;
    let player = a.name;
    let dt = a.Date;
    let score = a.score;

    if (!end.hasOwnProperty(game)) {
        end[game] = {};
    }

    if (!end[game].hasOwnProperty(player)) {
        end[game][player] = {
            "Total_score": 0,
            "Played_games": []
        };
    }

    let existingDate = end[game][player]["Played_games"].find(tmp => Object.keys(tmp)[0] === dt);

    /* Activate ONLY if you need the best 3 days, and not the best 3 games
    if (existingDate) {
        existingDate[dt] += score;
    } else {
        end[game][player]["Played_games"].push({ [dt]: score });
    }
    */
    
    // Deactivate if above is activated - this one is making
    // individual entries for days and games, and allowing
    // a single day to appear multiple times - it's the games that matter
    end[game][player]["Played_games"].push({ [dt]: score });

    // Sort the Played_games array based on the scores in descending order
    end[game][player]["Played_games"].sort((a, b) => Object.values(b)[0] - Object.values(a)[0]);

    // Keep only the top 3 results, and remove the rest
    end[game][player]["Played_games"] = end[game][player]["Played_games"].slice(0, 3);

    // Set the total score now, with only the best 3 for the current player
    end[game][player]["Total_score"] = 0;
    // Loop through all the available date:score pairs for the current player
    end[game][player]["Played_games"].forEach(function(tmpDate){
        // Add the score for the current date to the total
        // for our current player
        for(tmpIndex in tmpDate) {
            end[game][player]["Total_score"] += tmpDate[tmpIndex];
        }
    });
});

// Once the filling up of the end object array is done
// sort the players by Total_score in descending order
for (let game in end) {
    end[game] = Object.entries(end[game]).sort((a, b) => b[1]["Total_score"] - a[1]["Total_score"]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(end));
```

The code above gives us:

```
{
    "tennis": [
        [
            "John",
            {
                "Total_score": 595,
                "Played_games": [
                    {
                        "21/12/2024": 220
                    },
                    {
                        "01/12/2024": 197
                    },
                    {
                        "25/12/2024": 178
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        [
            "Klaas",
            {
                "Total_score": 321,
                "Played_games": [
                    {
                        "10/11/2024": 188
                    },
                    {
                        "11/11/2024": 88
                    },
                    {
                        "13/11/2024": 45
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Its working in a nice and understandable solution. I'd love to see how it's possible to make more than one game on a specific date.

Comment: FiddlingAway may i ask another question. Is is possible in a simple way that if a person plays 5 games only the best 3 are counting for the total? So if someone is playing 5 games of tennis with scores 130, 140, 125, 180, 160 only 180, 160 and 140 is counting for the total.

Comment: A bit more information is needed for your second request. Five games exactly, or >= 5 games? Also, would that be when there 5 (or >= 5) games in one day, or in total? Should anything happen with individual date listings (only the best three are displayed etc), or should all days / individual dates be listed there?

Comment: Regarding your first question / requirement - please see the edited code. The change / addition sums up the points for the specific day.

Comment: The idea is that the best 3 of all scores (multiple dates) of one gametype from one person should be counted.

Comment: When the best 3 scores are calculated it is also nice to order the results by total_score

Comment: Please see the edited code (third hidden snippet).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great help and the quick responses!